# How do you give access to vscode to files in your desktop, downloads, and documents on MacOS?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I initially didn't allow VS Code when it was asking for access to my desktop, downloads, and documents. Now I need help giving it access.

I tried searching through the settings and checking to see if I could find a way but couldn't. Maybe I am not looking hard enough or in the right places.

Answer (score 1):

You can find it in Privacy & Security, Files and Folders. Scroll down to Visual Studio Code:

[image]